# non-blocking socket client with blocking server

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, openssl

I need to send data to the site without receiving delays in single connection. I have not found a better way than using asynchronous socket. I thought that site uses a blocking connection and I do not have access to server.
I run the tests on my server, which also uses a blocking connection. I wrote a simple program on php.

```
<?php
$ms=round(microtime(true)*1000).' '.mt_rand(111,999);
sleep(1);
file_put_contents('ms.txt',$ms."\r\n",FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);
echo $ms;
?>
```

My client program I wrote on c++ using non-blocking sockets.
This is my c++ non-blocking socket client:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
 
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 struct sockaddr_in sa;
 int s=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
 sa.sin_family=AF_INET;
 sa.sin_port=htons(443);
 sa.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("100.1.1.1");//ip of my site 
 socklen_t socklen=sizeof(sa);
 int one = 1;
 setsockopt(s, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &one, sizeof(one));
 connect(s,(struct sockaddr *)&sa,sizeof(sa));
 int flags;
 if((flags = fcntl(s, F_GETFL, 0))==-1)flags=0;
 fcntl(s, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
 SSL *ssl;
 SSL_CTX *ctx=SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
 ssl=SSL_new(ctx);
 SSL_set_fd(ssl,s);
 fd_set fds;
 FD_ZERO(&fds);
 FD_SET(s, &fds);
 while(1){
  int err=SSL_connect(ssl);
  if(err==1){break;}
  int decodedError = SSL_get_error(ssl,err);
  if(decodedError==SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ){
   int result=select(s+1,&fds,NULL,NULL,NULL);
   if(result==-1){
    printf("Read-select error.\n");
    return -1;
   }
  }else if(decodedError==SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE){
   int result=select(s+1,NULL,&fds,NULL,NULL);
   if(result==-1){
    printf("Write-select error.\n");
    return -1;
   }
  }else{
   printf("Error creating SSL connection. err=%x\n", decodedError);
   return -1;
  }
 }
 for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
  SSL_write(ssl,"GET /ms.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: site.co.uk\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n",95);
 }
 sleep(20);
 close(s);
 return 0;
}
```

Client finished work without an error.
But in my file ms.txt on server I have 1 second delay of each request.

```
1621710871272 236
1621710872275 765
1621710873279 549
1621710874281 250
1621710875284 559
1621710876288 607
1621710877291 787
1621710878294 627
1621710879297 352
1621710880300 305
1621710881302 860
1621710882306 649
1621710883309 222
1621710884312 974
1621710885315 628
1621710886317 184
1621710887320 532
1621710888322 142
1621710889325 161
1621710890329 114
```

What I'm doing wrong and how I can send data in one connection without receiving delay?

Comment: Apparently, _one connection_ is handled by one server process. If that process delays, it delays - no way around it. And you probably don't even want a way around and get the individual responses mixed up.

Comment: @Armali, but a non-blocking socket makes it possible to send requests asynchronously, without waiting for a response to arrive. But my next request is sent only after the answer has come. This can be seen from the delay time. Although I send all requests at once.

Comment: No, what _can be seen_ is only when the request is handled by the server process; indeed you _send all requests at once_, but they are buffered in the server OS and taken one by one by the server application process. You may verify this by looking at the network traffic.

Comment: @Armali looks like you are rigth! I tested socket client in blocking mode and saw the difference. Thanks!
1621763711727
1621763712978
1621763714229